# Python import doesn't work when file is imported

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-import, python-module

I am having difficulties to understand how the python importer works..
I have a python script (fractalDimension.py) that imports a submodule ("greedyColoring.py") using:

```
from boxCovering.greedyColoring import *
```

It works fine when I call it directly:

```
python fractalDimension.py
```

The problem began when I moved the script to a folder and added a main script which imports the fractalDimension.py because now the import of the boxCovering sub module doesn't work.

In the main script I call the fractalDimension method:

```
import fractality.fractalDimension as fd

fd.calculate()
```

but when I run

```
python main.py
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
  import fractality.fractalDimension as fd
File "fractalDimension.py", line 11, in <module>
  from boxCovering.greedyColoring import *
ImportError: No module named 'boxCovering'
```

**Directory layout:**

```
main.py
fractalDimension/
 |
 +-- __init__.py
 +-- fractalDimension.py
 +-- boxCovering/
     |
     +-- __init__.py
     +-- greedyColoring.py
```

Both init files are empty

Why python cannot find the boxCovering module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that python is searching for a **top-level** package called `boxCovering` inside the `PYTHONPATH` and none exists (you have only a *sub*-package inside the current directory, but this isn't searched).

When you want to import a subpackage/submodule you want to use a(n explicit) relative import:

```
from .boxCovering.greedyColoring import *
```

note the `.` (dot) at the beginning.

Alternatively use the absolute import:

```
from fractality.fractalDimension.boxCovering.greedyColoring import *
```

---

In python2 the import allowed an implicit relative import, which is what you are trying to do. In that case the import:

```
from boxCovering import X
```

done in the way you are doing could have two different meanings:

- import of the subpackage `boxCovering` of the `fractalDimension` package
- import of the top-level package `boxCovering`

In python3 (see the [What's new?](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax) and relevant [PEP 0328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)) they decided that such an import *always* has the second meaning. If you want a relative import you have to *explicitly* state so by using the relative syntax, which uses a dot at the beginning of the module name.

Each dot means go to one directory above so `.` means the current directory while `..` means the parent directory (as in unix paths) etc.

You can enable this semantics on python2 adding:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

at the top of your files.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bakuriu for the answer and the explanation. The dot at the beginning of the import made it work.